# How to add data line to a 'Extended Linear Address - 04' of a Intel Hex File using python bincopy package?

Tags: python, python-3.x, binaryfiles, 32-bit, file-format

Data:

> line1
> :2000A00006156745805F0614C2FE3CEB0284029506F067101F0006F1C21E82087AE86E1CA3
>
> line2  :02000004803347
>
> line3
> :2000A00006156745805F0614C2FE3CEB0284029506F067101F0006F1C21E82087AE86E1CA3
>
> line4  :02000004803545
>
> line5
> :20B00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000030
>
> line6
> :20B02000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010
>
> line7
> :20B040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000F0

I want to write data line with address **803300B0**, which shall be placed at **line4** ideally. But bincopy package does not allow a 32-bit address input, somehow it only take 16-bit address.

```
f = bincopy.BinFile("file.hex")
linedata = ":2000B00006156745805F0614C2FE3CEB0284029506F067101F0006F1C21E82087AE86E1CA3"
f.add(linedata, overwrite=False)
```

But the above code throws below error:

```
    raise UnsupportedFileFormatError()
bincopy.UnsupportedFileFormatError: Unsupported file format.
```

Comment: You don't add strings, you add `Segment` objects.  If you already have the data and the CRC, why don't you just use an editor to insert it there?  You already have the right prefix.

Comment: @TimRoberts:
"You don't add strings, you add Segment objects." - Completely agree with you on this.
But as i am building a tool/exe for manipulating IntelHex files, i cannot use a editor for inserting a line into a ***Segment***.

Comment: In that case, you need to load the whole file into memory, modify the segment you need to extend, then write it back out.  I'll also point out that ANYTHING you need to do with hex files can be done with the all-powerful "srecord" tools:  http://srecord.sourceforge.net/  .  It's like sendmail: it can do anything including make your coffee, if you can figure out how to spell it.